# Why is my React debounce handler never called?

Tags: reactjs, lodash, onchange, debouncing

I'm using React 16.13.0 and lodash.  I was recommended to use debounce as a way to properly send search requests to my server as a user types in their search term. I implemented this ...

```
...

const handleChange = (event, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults) => {
  console.log("search term:" + searchTerm);
  const query = event.target.value;
  setSearchTerm(query);
  if (!query) {
    setSearchResults( [] );
  } else {
    doSearch(query, searchTerm, setSearchResults);
  }
}

const getDebouncedHandler = (e, handler, delay) => {
  console.log("value:" + e.target.value);
  _.debounce(handler, delay);
}
...

const Search = (props) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  const renderSearchResults = ...

  return (
    <div className="searchForm">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={(e) => {getDebouncedHandler(e, (e) => {handleChange(e, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults); }, 100)}}
      />
      {renderSearchResults()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

The problem is, although I see my "getDebouncedHandler" method getting called, I don't think

```
_.debounce(handler, delay);
```

is doing anything because I never see the method listed there invoked.  What else do I need to do to get debounce handler invoked properly?

**Edit:** Adding in the logic I'm using for "doSearch"

```
const doSearch = (query, searchTerm, setSearchResults) => {
  console.log("before fetch, with query:" + query);
  const searchUrl = "/coops/?contains=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
  fetch(searchUrl, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("returning data for " + searchTerm + " query:" + query);
      console.log(data);
      if (query === searchTerm) {
        console.log("setting search results for search term:" + searchTerm);
        setSearchResults(data);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to implement this :

1. Don't debounce the `onChange` handler, this will cause a bad UX because some characters will be lost.
2. Create a debounced version of your expensive function. Usually it's where you make a API call. I assume that's `doSearch` in your case.
3. Keep the debounced function outside your component if your using a functional component, or use `useMemo` to keep the reference, otherwise it will be created every time, and it will not be very useful (it has an internal state to keep track of the last time it was called and other stuff ...).
4. Keep in mind that when you call `_.debounce` it returns a function.
5. Use `useEffect` to call your debounced function when the search query changes.

The code :

```
// Your expensive function
const doSearch = (query, callback) => {
  const searchUrl = "/coops/?contains=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
  fetch(searchUrl, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      callback(data);
    });
}

// The debounced version
const doSearchDebounced = _.debounce(doSearch, 100);

const Search = (props) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  // Keep track of the last request ID
  const lastRequestId = useRef(null);

  // This hook will run when searchTerm changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!searchTerm) {
      setSearchResults([]);
      return;
    }

    // Update the last request ID
    const requestId = performance.now();
    lastRequestId.current = requestId;

    // Let the debounced function do it's thing
    doSearchDebounced(searchTerm, (results) => {
      // Only set the data if the current request is the last one
      if (requestId === lastRequestId.current) {
        setSearchResults(results);
      }
    });

  }, [searchTerm]);

  // No debounce here, just getting the user's input
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const renderSearchResults = ...

  return (
    <div className="searchForm">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {renderSearchResults()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my question to include the logic for my "doSearch" method because I'm still having an issue.  If I type in a word like "credit" quickly, it will only fire off a few requests (for example) -- a search with "c" another with "cre" and another with "credit".  However, the results of these searches come back out of order and it seems like the last one overwrites the previous ones.  Any way to cancel the previous requests or guarantee that the last request's search data is what is ultimately displayed?

Comment: Yeah that's a common problem with async function calls in react. I updated my answer with a possible solution : I added a callback param to `doSearch`, and in the component I use a ref to keep track of the last request ID, and only set the data if the current request is the last one.

Comment: I use `performance.now()` for the request ID, but you can use other tool to generate a uuid

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Hi Ramrami. Can you explain why you use the request-id & the ref? I'm trying to understand your solution

Answer (score 0):

`_.debounce(handler, delay)` returns a function - you have to use that function as the event handler.

So create a function:

```
const debouncedHandleChange = _.debounce(handleChange, delay)
```

In the jsx:

```
onChange = {e => debouncedHandleChange(e, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults)}
```

You have to debounce only fetching of the search results not the typing, i.e. if you debounce setting the searchTerm, the searchTerm won't be set until the user stops typing. So until he stops typing, whatever he typed won't be displayed. So change the code accordingly and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: When you define the onChange with "debouncedHandleChange(e, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults)", are those parameters (e.g. "e", "searchTerm", etc ...) supposed to get passed to the "handleChange" functcion that is a part of "_.debounce(handleChange, delay)"?  That isn't happening for me.

Comment: Yes, whatever parameters you provide is supposed to be passed to the handleChange function.

Comment: Oh ok I do see an object for "event", (the "e" parameter) but the target attribute is null.  How do I get the value of what is entered into the text box?  I thought it was event.target.value.

Comment: what?! event.target.value is how you get the value.

Comment: I think there's something else going on here.  So I "think" I got the value of what is typed in the textbox by using "debouncedHandleChange(e, e.target.value, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults)}" instead, however the problem now is unless I type really slowly, characters are getting lost as I type.  If I type the word "credit" real fast, ony "cedt" (or variations) appear in the textbox.

Comment: Yeah that's because you might be debouncing the setting of the term. You should debounce only the setting of search results.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here.

1. The `lodash.debounce` method returns a function. You have to then call it.
2. The event you are passing is a synthetic and is not kept around for later use, so its best you pass what you need (`event.target.value`) immediately.

So your code would look like this;

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import _ from 'lodash';

const handleChange = (value, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults) => {
  // expect a value here instead of an event
  console.log("search term:" + searchTerm);
  const query = value;
  setSearchTerm(query);
  if (!query) {
    console.log('no search');
  } else {
    console.log('do search');
  }
}

const getDebouncedHandler = (e, handler, delay) => {
  console.log("value : " + e.target.value, handler);
  _.debounce(handler, delay)(e.target.value);
  // 1. call the function
  // 2. pass the function the value you need later
}

const Search = (props) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const renderSearchResults = () => <div>results</div>

  return (
    <div className="searchForm">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={(e) => {getDebouncedHandler(e, (e) => {handleChange(e, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults); }, 100)}}
      />
      {renderSearchResults()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

Here's a codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-liskov-dj07t?file=/src/App.js:0-1268

To clarify, I kept my answer as to keep your code in tact as is. But this is not a normal pattern and you should use the style that Ram is referring to, where you create the the instance of the debounced function, and call it, instead of creating a new debounced function on every keystroke, which is not ideal.

Comment: Am I supposed to be replacing your "// 1. " and "// 2." with anything?  Also I'm noticing with your code the first argument to "handleChange" (event) seems to contain the character that is typed, as opposed to an event object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `_.debounce` returns a debounced function, it doesn't denounce the call to the function.

```
...

const handleChange = (event, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults) => {
  console.log("search term:" + searchTerm);
  const query = event.target.value;
  setSearchTerm(query);
  if (!query) {
    setSearchResults( [] );
  } else {
    doSearch(query, searchTerm, setSearchResults);
  }
}

const getDebouncedHandler = (e, handler, delay) => {
  console.log("value:" + e.target.value);
  return _.debounce(handler, delay);
}

const denouncedHandler = getDebouncedHandler((e, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults) => {
  handleChange(e, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults);
}, 
100);
...

const Search = (props) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  const renderSearchResults = ...

  return (
    <div className="searchForm">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={(e) => denouncedHandler(e, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, setSearchResults)}
      />
      {renderSearchResults()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```